# wxpython-how to find id of button which raised the event

Tags: wxpython

I have created 3 Buttons in a panel they all have same onclick event, now I have to find which button has called onclick event and it’s ID

```
k=5
j=400
    for i in range(k):
      j=j+20
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnButton2Button,id=j)

def OnButton2Button(self,event):
     #what should i code here to get id or name of button which raised click event
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the object itself?

```
button = event.GetEventObject()
```

Then you can call `GetId()`, `GetName()`, `GetLabel()`...